# How parse JSON to C# and then correctly get data or why my method doesn't work

Tags: c#, json

I found next code which can deserialize JSON to C#. But when I tried deserilize "[{...}, {...}]" array of objects. I have next error: InvalidCast exeption cannot convert from List to Dictionary. Then I changed my JSON to format "{"array: "[{...}, {...}]"}". Error dissapear and I have Dictionary which has 1 key with array value, but I can't understand how get access to data in this array. How I can deserialize any correctly JSON into C# primitives. So many methods have been tried I all was wrong.

```
public class DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) { this.WriteValue(writer, value); }

        private void WriteValue(JsonWriter writer, object value)
        {
            var t = JToken.FromObject(value);
            switch (t.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    this.WriteObject(writer, value);
                    break;
                case JTokenType.Array:
                    this.WriteArray(writer, value);
                    break;
                default:
                    writer.WriteValue(value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void WriteObject(JsonWriter writer, object value)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            var obj = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
            foreach (var kvp in obj)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
                this.WriteValue(writer, kvp.Value);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        private void WriteArray(JsonWriter writer, object value)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            var array = value as IEnumerable<object>;
            foreach (var o in array)
            {
                this.WriteValue(writer, o);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return ReadValue(reader);
        }

        private object ReadValue(JsonReader reader)
        {
            while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
            {
                if (!reader.Read()) throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected Token when converting IDictionary<string, object>");
            }

            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    return ReadObject(reader);
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    return this.ReadArray(reader);
                case JsonToken.Integer:
                case JsonToken.Float:
                case JsonToken.String:
                case JsonToken.Boolean:
                case JsonToken.Undefined:
                case JsonToken.Null:
                case JsonToken.Date:
                case JsonToken.Bytes:
                    return reader.Value;
                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException
                        (string.Format("Unexpected token when converting IDictionary<string, object>: {0}", reader.TokenType));
            }
        }

        private object ReadArray(JsonReader reader)
        {
            IList<object> list = new List<object>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        break;
                    default:
                        var v = ReadValue(reader);

                        list.Add(v);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return list;
                }
            }

            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
        }

        private object ReadObject(JsonReader reader)
        {
            var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                        var propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

                        if (!reader.Read())
                        {
                            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
                        }

                        var v = ReadValue(reader);

                        obj[propertyName] = v;
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndObject:
                        return obj;
                }
            }

            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); }
    }
```

All code above I found in the answers here, and for other peoples it works. This is how I used it:

```
var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(StringJSON, new DictionaryConverter());
```

Comment: What is your json and what you are trying to do?

Comment: "[{"name":"First","time":" 2 дн. 3 ч. 7 мин."},{"name":"Second","time":" 27 дн. 23 ч. 7 мин."}]" This I want transform to C# primitives to work with this information. But how doest it do correctly? @eser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an object like

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var jsonstring = @"[{""name"":""First"","time"":"" 2 дн. 3 ч. 7 мин.""},{""name"":""Second"",""time"":"" 27 дн. 23 ч. 7 мин.""}]";

var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonstring)
```

Comment: but I always have different objects, hundreds maybe. And for each must be created class? No easy and more universal way?( @Eser

Comment: Yes there is. But this all I can say by reading your question. Your problem is not related with *JsonConverter*. Have you read this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: how I can help you to help me? Can you get some keywords about another ways or references with material? @Eser

Comment: Your real  json for ex?

Comment: You are right about XY problem, but I can't understand what's my problem and how resolve it. I just want realise needed functionality. I tried with class and maybe something happens. Thank you anyway for new information. @Eser

Comment: `but I always have different objects, hundreds maybe` Of course your objects can be mapped to a model. But since you don't want to share your json, nothing more can be done by me. Good luck with you.